# Error documenting Substrate Pallet Storagemap tems when using `\\!`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, substrate

Im adding some documentation around `lib.rs` in my pallet implementation as follows

````rust
//! ## Genomes
//! * Key 1 -> AccountId + GenomeHash
//! * Value -> Genome structure
//!
//! ```
//! use frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap;
//! use frame_support::Blake2_128Concat;
//! use pallet_genomes::Config;
//!
//! #[pallet::storage]
//! #[pallet::getter(fn get_genomes)]
//! pub(super) type Genomes<T: Config> =
//!     StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, (Vec<u8>, T::AccountId), Vec<Genes<T>>>;
//! ```
````

Though this throws errors when I execute `cargo run test` it throws following errors

```
#[pallet::storage]
  |   ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `pallet`
 StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, (Vec<u8>, T::AccountId), Vec<Genes<T>>>;
|           ^ not allowed in type signatures
pub(super) type Genomes<T: Config> 
  ^^^^^ there are too many leading `super` keywords
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: What's `pallet`? It is not imported in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggests you need to import what you use in the doc comments (it doesn't use the `use` statements that are already in the file).

`use pallet::*;`

(You can prefix this with `#`  if you don't want this to show up in the docs).